# Why this docker container does not run Chrome using $DISPLAY?

Tags: docker, google-chrome

I want to crawl something from a web application that is behind a login page that has captch.

Thus I can't use **headless** chrome and **Xvfb**. I need to have a real **head** or GUI that user can interact with.

In [this link](https://thespecguy.medium.com/launching-google-chrome-on-docker-container-a7dc2ba2d5) it's explained that we need to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable, and map `/tmp/.X11-unix` as a volume.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:lts-bullseye-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install gnupg wget -y && \
    wget --quiet --output-document=- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-archive.gpg && \
    sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y --no-install-recommends && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

And based on the image built using that `Dockerfile` this is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    accounts:
        image: custom-chrome
        container_name: crawl
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        environment:
            - Key=Value
            - DISPLAY=:0
        restart: always
        command: tail -f /dev/null
        volumes:
            - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
```

And when I run it, and use `docker exec -it crawl bash` to run `google-chrome --no-sandbox` I get this error:

```
[88:110:0930/091140.468813:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[88:88:0930/091140.474099:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[88:88:0930/091140.474111:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
bash-5.1# [0930/091140.494571:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(354)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

While I can see that `echo $DISPLAY` actually prints something, and `/tmp/.X11-unix` also exists inside the container.

Why it does not work?

Comment: Have you found a solution for it?

Comment: @VítorResende, nope.